# django form: ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: django, forms

I am working on an existing project and I wanna add a django form to a page. The application is called wireless, and under wireless directory I have forms.py, with some code like:

```
from django import forms    
class WirelessScanForm(forms.ModelForm):
        time = forms.DateTimeField(label='When', widget=AdminSplitDateTime())
        prob = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[x.sniffer.plug_ip for x in
                         SurveyRouterSniffer.objects.all()])
```

In views.py I do the following:

```
from wireless import forms

form = forms.WirelessScanForm()
return render_response(request, 'wireless/crack.html',
            { 'scheduledScans' : scheduledScans,
              'form': form})
```

I'm very new to django so any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't really know how the error could be any clearer. For a modelform, you need to specify a model class.

If this isn't a form based on a model, don't inherit from `forms.ModelForm`, just use an ordinary `forms.Form`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a Meta class to your forms.ModelForm specifying which model to base the format on.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm

```
class WirelessScanForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WirelessScan
```